# Nexus 3 Speed Hub Up Steeper Hills Turns Weird

Tags: hub, nexus

I have a [Linus Roadster Sport](http://www.linusbike.com/products/roadster-sport) that has a Nexus 3 speed hub on it. It shifts gears just fine but I noticed recently that when I have it in first gear to go up a somewhat steep hill, the pedals turn very freely like it's turning something inside of the hub, but that isn't transferring to my back wheel to be able to power myself up the hill. Similar situation with my driveway. Pedal up and then I pretty much have to get off the bike and walk it up because my pedals just spin in place while the hub makes a unique sound.

Comment: If you record the sound it might help.

Comment: @Batman Thanks for responding. I recorded a video and got to looking around and watching it really closely tonight and I determined the problem is that the wheel was rubbing into the inner side of the frame. The nut that resides under Nexus hub was loose. So when I would be going up a hill and pulling a lot of force onto the bike, it was causing the wheel to move into the frame. Problem solved!